# Tansparent video on Website displays with a black square

Tags: html, video, transparency, after-effects

I would like to add a video on my Website with an auto play, but i've got a problem. My video is transparent and i would like to keep this transparency. My web browser adds a black square behind the video.

I don't know how to fix this problem, my video is a .MOV but it also doesn't work with a GIF. Do you know if I have to change the codec when i export the video from After effect ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't render a video with alpha channel.
The best way is to render your composition as **png** or **psd** sequence, then create **gif** animation in photoshop.

Comment: You can render videos with an alpha channel. For example using Apple ProRes 4444, but the `<video>` tag does not allow these codecs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats